# Object Refrence not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, basic-authentication

in my asp web project . 
i have 3 pages named as reg.aspx,`log.aspx`, `Default.aspx`.
on reg.aspx, i want user to regiester themself. on reg page, i have 2 `textbox` , `textbox1`,`textbox2`, and a `button` control button1.

for this pupose i am stroring their username and pass in `web.config` file. 
here is the my `web.config` code

```
 <configuration>
        <system.web>
          <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="Log.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx">
              <credentials passwordFormat="MD5">
              </credentials>
            </forms>
          </authentication>
          <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
          </authorization>  
          <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
          <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        </system.web>  
       <location path="Reg.aspx">
         <system.web>
           <authorization>
             <allow users="*"/>
           </authorization>
         </system.web>
       </location>
    </configuration>
```

and on button click of reg page i have written this code ,

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Configuration cfg = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
        ConfigurationSectionGroup cgs = cfg.SectionGroups["system.web"];
        AuthenticationSection Aus=(AuthenticationSection)cgs.Sections["Authentication"];
        Aus.Forms.Credentials.Users.Add(new FormsAuthenticationUser(TextBox1.Text,FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(TextBox2.Text,"MD5")));
        cfg.Save();
        Response.Write("Registration Success");

    }
```

but when i try to reg user it throw null refrences . where is the problem in my code .

Comment: What line is throwing the NullReferenceException?

Comment: Configuration cfg is null

Comment: If you want the root web configuration, then call `WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null)`

Comment: when i used your code then this line is throwing null
AuthenticationSection Aus=(AuthenticationSection)cgs.Sections["Authentication"];

Comment: help please. what's wrong with code

Comment: When things throw NullReferenceExceptions, it means you're trying to use objects that aren't initialized. Find out what didn't get initialized, then go look up the appropriate documentation on MSDN to make sure you're using the object properly so that it can get initialized.